# Setting "require server name indication" with c# using Microsoft.web.adminsitration

Tags: c#, iis

Anyone who have some code that shows how the require SNI flag can be set with c# code on IIS website bindings.

I already know how to set the binding :

```
Binding newBinding = site.Bindings.CreateElement("binding");
newBinding["bindingInformation"] = bindingsString;
newBinding["certificateHash"] = certificate.GetCertHashString();
newBinding["certificateStoreName"] = store.Name;
newBinding["protocol"] = "https";
```

I am not sure what key I need to set to set the SNI flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that we are just editing the host xml ApplicationHost.config file located at %WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config

and it was easy to see what flags got changed when settings was changed. sslFlag="1" is the SNI required flag.

```
  <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:www.c1get.net" sslFlags="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found in applicationHost.config that SNI has changed SSL Flag to be 3 on Windows Server 2012.

```
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:example.com" sslFlags="3" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:www.example.com" sslFlags="3" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:example.net" sslFlags="3" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:www.example.net" sslFlags="3" />
```

Comment: need to test that, I was using 2012 R2 when I found my answer earlier and got everything working with sslFlag="1"

Comment: I use sslFlags=3 for SNI Support. I found documentation from this link. http://jadia.us/1yLKFVh

Comment: thanks for the link. 3 is for a centralized store. I dont use that. 1 is correct for me